# @PostConstruct method called twice when making the module containing the EJB a dependency of another module

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

My maven project structure looks like this:

```
test_project-parent
  |test_project-ejb.jar
  |test_project-depl.jar
  |test_project-web.war
  |test_project-ear.ear
```

My 3 modules: ejb, depl and web are packaged into the EAR.

I have an EJB in my ejb module that looks like this:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class StartupBean {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @PostConstruct
    private void sayHello () {
        System.out.println("HELLO !!!");
    }
    }
```

My problem is that that the `sayHello()` method is executed twice.

Here's the output from the log:

```
00:16:13,803 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 113) HELLO !!!
00:16:13,803 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 117) HELLO !!!
```

My ejb module is a dependency of my web module.

When I remove the dependency it works fine (the method is called once as it should be).

The pom.xml of my web module looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.testing</groupId>
        <artifactId>test_project</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>test_project-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>test_project-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>${test_project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

NOTE: I have read all the related posts and found no answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error. I needed to change the scope of my dependency to provided, because the way it was the dependency was packaged inside the war archive in it's lib folder. So, basically, my ejb module was deployed twice, and hence the double execution of the @PostConstruct method.

I added `<scope>provided</scope>` to the ejb dependency inside my web module pom.xml and everything works fine. The ejb module is no longer packaged inside the lib folder of the war archive and the @PostConstruct method is called only once.